# how to remove a div by pressing on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var i=0;

     var inputs = new Array();
     var $type,$name, $label;    

     $("#txt").click(function(){
          var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + i);

     newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + i + 
          '" id="textbox' + inputs.length + '" value="" >' + '<input type="button" id="x'+inputs.length+'"value="x">');

     newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#holder");

     inputs.push(['text','textbox'+i,'textboxtx'+i]);

     i++;


});

$("#chk").click(function(){

     var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + inputs.length);

     newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
          '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox' + i + 
          '" id="checkbox' + inputs.length + '" value="" >' + '<input type="button" id="x'+inputs.length +'"value="x">');

     newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#holder");

     inputs.push(['checkbox','checkbox'+i,'checkbotx'+i]);

     i++;


});

$("#rad").click(function(){
     var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + inputs.length);

     newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
          '<input type="radio" name="radio' + i + 
          '" id="radio' + inputs.length + '" value="" >' + '<input type="button" id="x'+inputs.length +'"value="x">');

     newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#holder");

     inputs.push(['radio','radio'+i,'radiot'+i]);

    i++;


});

$("#btn").click(function(){
     var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + inputs.length);

     newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
          '<input type="button" name="button' + i + 
          '" id="button' + inputs.length + '" value="button'+i+'" >' + '<input type="button" id="x'+inputs.length +'"value="x">');

     newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#holder");

     inputs.push(['button','button'+i,'buttont'+i]);

     i++;

     $("#holder").append(inputs);


});
```

in the code below i was addind dynamically text fields buttons radion ..etc by pressing on a button (creating divs that countains the inputs)

```
 for(a=0 ;a<inputs.length ;a++){

     $("#x"+a).click(function(){
          $("#Div"+a).remove();    
     });
   };
})
```

in this part i'm trying to remove certain div but it's not working!
Javascript/jQuery aren't languages I use often.
All help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
<div>
 <div style="display:inline">

<input type="button" id="txt" value="Add TextBox" style="" /><br>
<input type="button" id="chk" value="Add CheckBox" style="" /><br>
<input type="button" id="rad" value="Add Radio" style="" /><br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Add Button" style="" /><br>

</div>
<div id="holder">
</div>




</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show html code also

Comment: I don't understand your problem properly your code for adding button text checkbox etc are working finn but click on x is not removing them is it your problem ?

Comment: yes adding is working fine but i can' remove them and i don't know what the error in for loop

Comment: after you created the element and add it to your dom, you can bind your eventlistener. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <div style="display:inline"> 
            <input type="button" id="txt" value="Add TextBox" style="" >
            <br> 
            <input type="button" id="chk" value="Add CheckBox" style="">
            <br> 
            <input type="button" id="rad" value="Add Radio" style="" >
            <br> 
            <input type="button" id="btn" value="Add Button" style="" >
            <br> 
        </div> 
        <div id="holder"> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var i=0;
            var inputs = new Array();
            var $type,$name, $label;    
            $("#txt").click(function(){
                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + i);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
                    '<input type="text" name="textbox'+i+'" id="textbox'+inputs.length+'" value="" ><input type="button" onclick="xtext(\''+i+'\')" id="xtext'+inputs.length+'" value="x">');
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#holder");
                inputs.push(['text','textbox'+i,'textboxtx'+i]);
                i++;
            });

            $("#chk").click(function(){

                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + inputs.length);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox'+i+'" id="checkbox'+inputs.length+'" value="" ><input type="button" onclick="xcheck(\''+i+'\')"  id="xcheck'+inputs.length +'"value="x">');
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#holder");
                inputs.push(['checkbox','checkbox'+i,'checkbotx'+i]);
                i++;
            });

            $("#rad").click(function(){
                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + inputs.length);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="radio" name="radio'+i+'" id="radio'+inputs.length+'" value="" ><input type="button" onclick="xradio(\''+i+'\')"  id="xradio'+inputs.length +'" value="x">');
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#holder");
                inputs.push(['radio','radio'+i,'radiot'+i]);
                i++;
            });

            $("#btn").click(function(){
                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + inputs.length);

                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="button" name="button'+i+'" id="button'+inputs.length+'" value="button'+i+'" ><input type="button" onclick="xbtn(\''+i+'\')"  id="xbtn'+inputs.length +'" value="x">');

                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#holder");
                inputs.push(['button','button'+i,'buttont'+i]);
                i++;
                $("#holder").append(inputs);


            });



        });
function xtext(id)
{
    $("#xtext"+id).remove();
    $("#textbox"+id).remove();

}
function xcheck(id)
{
    $("#xcheck"+id).remove();
    $("#checkbox"+id).remove();

}
function xbtn(id)
{
    $("#xbtn"+id).remove();
    $("#button"+id).remove();

}
function xradio(id)
{
    $("#xradio"+id).remove();
    $("#radio"+id).remove();

}
</script>   
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: thank you!! but i want also to remove the div created as well

Comment: $("#holder").remove();

Comment: function xtext(id)
{
    $("#Div"+id).remove();

Comment: how can i remove inputs[id]?